# jQuery swapping DIV content optimization

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I have the following ***-working-*** code that I would like to optimize using a tertiary operator and giving the object a 'state' var.  However I am confused as to where exactly to put the click event to accomplish this.

HTML (supports multiple divs with the following layout):

```
<div class="adbox">
  <div class="ad-image">Image 2 Goes Here <a class="swap-content" href="#">Next</a></div>
  <div class="ad-content">Ad 2 text goes here <a class="swap-image" href="#">Back</a></div>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
<script lang="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var speed = 500;
    $('a.swap-content').click(function() {
      var myad = $(this).parent().parent();
      $(myad).find('div.ad-image').fadeOut(speed, function(){
        $(myad).find('div.ad-content').fadeIn(speed)
      });
    });
    $('a.swap-image').click(function() {
      var myad = $(this).parent().parent();
      $(myad).find('div.ad-content').fadeOut(speed, function(){
        $(myad).find('div.ad-image').fadeIn(speed)
      });
    });                            
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What's the question exactly ?

Comment: Clarify, I would like to rewrite this as one function to swap the divs (as it does now), rather than having 2 separate functions (one for each div) - ie. one click event that handles swapping back and forth using a tertiary operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var speed = 500;
    $('.adbox').find('a').click(function() {
        var self = $(this); 
        self.parent().fadeOut(speed, function(){
            self.parent().siblings('div').fadeIn(speed)
        });
    });                   
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qXqbS/)

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to accomplish (and better because it doesn't require an if/else or tertiary operator) thank you.  One quick question with this however, is *if* I have another <a></a> link (which I could always use button instead), that link would be attached to this function as well, I presume I could use "find('a.switch') in place of the find('a') in order to attach only to the 'switchable' links.

Comment: Also, thank you for the 'Demo', I have never seen that site before and it will come in very useful for other stuff I want to test out.

Comment: you're absolutely correct about your first question. Or you can use `$('.adbox a.switch')` instead of `$('.adbox').find('a.switch')`. However it's slightly faster with `.find()`